# Proving sufficient conditions for immersed submanifolds to be embedded

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

Should I say anything else to prove the following from Professor Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds text? Thank you.

Prove Proposition 5.21 (sufficient conditions for immersed submanifolds to be embedded). Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold. If any of the following holds, then $S$ is embedded.

(a) $S$ has codimension $0$ in $M.$

(b) The inclusion map $S\subseteq M$ is proper.

(c) S is compact.

$\textit{Proof.}$ If $(a)$ holds then Theorem 4.5 (Inverse Function Theorem for Manifolds) shows that the inclusion map $\iota : S\hookrightarrow M$ is an open map. The result follows from Proposition 4.22 where we suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary, and $F: M\to N$ is an injective smooth immersion. If any of the following holds, then $F$ is a smooth embedding.

(a) $F$ is an open or closed map.

(b) $F$ is a proper map.

(c) $M$ is compact.

(d) $M$ has empty boundary and $\dim M = \dim N.$

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false, at least (c). Take $f : \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = (\cos \theta, \sin 3\theta)$. This is an immersion, $\mathbb{S}^1$ is compact, but $f$ is not an embedding.

Comment: But this proposition in our textbook says that it would be an embedding?

Comment: Is there any other assumption like injectivity ?

Comment: That would be from theorem 4.5 i believe

Comment: The definition of "immersed submanifold" that I use in my book is "a subset endowed with a topology (not necessarily the subspace topology) with respect to which it is a topological manifold, and a smooth structure with respect to which the inclusion map is a smooth immersion." So injectivity is part of the definition.

Comment: I think it is not a standard definition, as in general, immersed submanifold refers to the image of an immersion between two manifolds.
It is clear to me now that what you stated is true. I will edit my answer when I have the time to.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's not standard. When I was writing ISM, I checked a number of other books and found that most introductory textbooks about differential geometry define immersed submanifolds as images of injective immersions (or some equivalent definition). Some examples are the books by Spivak, Boothby, Jeffrey Lee, Tu, and Michor. I'm aware that it's common in minimal surface theory to talk about immersed submanifolds as images of (not necessarily injective) immersions; but I wouldn't call that a "standard definition."

Comment: You may be right. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Immersed_submanifolds) states at first my definition, and then says that more narrowly, one can consider yours.

Comment: Didier or prof @JackLee what's the definition of codimension/dimension of immersed smooth submanifolds here? so far i only know of dimension/codimension for smooth manifolds and smooth embedded submanifolds